# Computing geodesic distances from structural data

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am attempting to compute geodesic distances on manifolds where structural data have been sparsely sampled.

First, off I am not well versed in the mathematics of differential geometry but I do have some knowledge (from an introductory differential geometry class in my undergrad). So forgive me if this question may seem simple.

The structural data that I have includes point locations of the manifold/surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ along with normals which describe the orientation of the manifold/surface.

In all examples in my DF class notes the type of manifold/surface was always known prior ( e.g. sphere, torus) to solving the geodesic equation and computing the geodesic distance. For these cases, it was easy to compute the metric since these surfaces are easy to parameterize. Now that I am trying to apply what I learned from the class (which was 10 years ago) in a real world scenario I am having a lot of trouble trying to determine how I solve it.

Surely there is a way to compute geodesic distances in this real world scenario. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have any sort of connectivity information, like a triangulation?

Comment: **K.Polthier, M.Schmies**, [Straightest Geodesics on Polyhedral Surfaces](http://polthier.info/articles/straightest/straightest_preprint.pdf) seems to be a good point to start.

Comment: @Rahul I can get a triangulated mesh using RBF reconstruction methods. But in order to get that I need to use RBF functions that input the distance between pairs of points. Currently I use euclidean distances but I would like to use geodesic distances instead. I would consider the normal data to provide connectivity information.

Comment: @Yuri This is an interesting paper. However, this requires you have an mesh in order to compute the geodesic distance. As I mentioned to Rahul I can get a mesh but I would prefer to compute the geodesic distances using gradient/normal data if that is possible. However, it does seem that you need some prior mesh/manifold in order to do this.

Comment: check Professor O'Neills http://www.math.ucla.edu/~bon/plotgeods.html

Comment: @janmarqz Thank you very much for that link. I think this will be extremely useful in providing a solution to my problem. I also have mathematica so I can quickly test a go through his examples.